# insertion of a date field from vf page

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, create-records

I have a requirement to insert a date field for opportunity on vf page.For the creation of record i used vf remoting.But when i am sending opportunity closed date from page to controller and trying to assign and insert.

> i'm getting exception as -Visualforce Remoting Exception: Unable to
>   convert date '2018-04-14' to Apex type Date.

Help will be appreciated.Thanks

Below is the Vf page and related controller code:

  
        
            
                
                    **Name:** 
                    **Amount:** 
                    **Closedate:**

```
    <!--- JS to create and delete opportunity using remoting---->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createOpp(){
        var OppName=document.getElementById('OppName').value;
        var OppAmount=document.getElementById('OppAmount').value;
        var OppClosedate=document.getElementById('OppCloseDate').value;
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.OpportunitiesWithAccounts.createOpportunity}',OppName,OppAmount,OppClosedate,                       
                                                  function(result,event){
   if(event.status){                                                                                                                             window.location.href= '/'+ result.Id;} },
  {escape: true});}
   </script>                                                    
</form>
```

```
 controller:

@RemoteAction
public static Opportunity createOpportunity(string oppName,Decimal amount,Date oppclosedate){ 
    opp.Name=oppName;
    opp.Amount=amount;
    opp.CloseDate=oppclosedate;
    opp.StageName='Qualification';           
    insert opp;
    return opp;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the method signature to get the `date` as `String`

```
createOpportunity(string oppName,Decimal amount,String oppclosedate)
```

Then assign date type attribute as:

```
opp.CloseDate=Date.parse(oppclosedate);
```

The date is getting returned as `String` type from `javaScript`. And so, fails at method signature itself.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Hey Hemant ,thanks for your quick response but still i am getting the exception.

Comment: Can you debug and check in the remote action method. What format the date is received? Is it received in `dd/mm/yyyy` format or `YYYY-MM-DD` format? If it is in this format: `YYYY-MM-DD` Try `Date.valueOf(oppclosedate);` instead of Date.parse

Comment: I tried that way also ,on console the format is 2018-04-14,and when i use Date.parse() or date.valueof() ,in both of the cases the format is 2018/04/14. Closedate is a date type field on Opportunity but i think somehow it is converting as datetime.

Comment: Just before doing valueOf, try replacing the '/' in date string with '-' (hyphen)

Comment: Hey it works hemant,Thanks a lot buddy :) From remoting when i replaced '/' with '-' its works .                                                                                     var OppClosedate=document.getElementById('OppCloseDate').value;
        var formattedCloseDate = (OppClosedate && OppClosedate.replace(/-/g, '-')) || '';